# Set off alarm when receiving text from a certain number?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, alarm

Is there a way to set off an alarm or make an audible notification when I receive a text message only from a certain number? I like to keep my notifications on vibrate while I sleep, but my district sends important notifications out sometimes in the middle of the night when I'm still asleep, so I'm not likely to notice the vibration.

Comment: Too bad they don't call with an automated message or something. That would be really easy to configure on your phone. Since it's just a text, the answer below is currently the only way to set up something like that as far as I know. The problem is, you still get email alerts (if enabled), and any other notifications that might audibly come your way at night, and, it's not just a quick enable Do Not Disturb every night/ disable in the morning thing (automatically with scheduled DND).

Answer (score 2):

Kinda. If you go to your sound settings and change the default text tone to "none" and then go to your contacts and change the text tone for whichever contact you want a notification from to something that DOES have sound, you will only get audible text alerts from that specific contact.

However this **will not** work if the phone is muted, or if Do-Not-Disturb is enabled.

I just tested this theory and it works.  Hope that helps!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the contact as a favorite and set the 'do not disturb', so only favorited contacts can call you etc.